# Workflow security exception with custom dll

Tags: development, workflow-activity

I have a workflow that uses a custom dll that I built. I have placed the dll into Inetpub website bin folder.

custom dll has 2 classes 
XMLUtilities now refferd to as xml 
Sharepoint helper now refered to as sharepoint

xml has a function called xml to dictionary wich takes a xmlfile and converts it to a string, string dictionary now refered to as xml function.

sharepoint has a function called getdocumentset now refered to as sharepoint function

xml function has only got generic c# dependencies
sharepoint funciton has dependencies on  Microsoft.Office.DocumentManagement.DocumentSets

here are the function as mentioned above

xml function

```
/// <summary>
/// DeSerializes a Serialized Dictionary
///<Dictionary>
///<Property Key="">Value</Property>
///<Property Key="">Value</Property>
///<Property Key="">Value</Property>
///<Property Key="">Value</Property>
///</Dictionary>
/// </summary>
/// <param name="xmldata"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static Dictionary<string, string> XmlToDictionary(string xmldata)
{
    string key = null;
    string value = null;
    Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    byte[] rawXmldata = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(xmldata);
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(rawXmldata);
    XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(stream);
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        if (reader.Name.Equals("Dictionary") )
        {
            continue;
        }
        if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
        {
            key = reader.GetAttribute(0);
        }
        if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text)
        {
            value = reader.Value;
        }
        if (key == null || value == null)
        {
            continue;
        }
        dictionary.Add(key, value);
        key = null;
        value = null;
    }
    return dictionary;
}
```

sharepoint function

```
public static DocumentSet GetDocumentSetByPath(SPWeb web, string path)
{
    SPFolder folder = web.GetFolder(path);
    return DocumentSet.GetDocumentSet(folder);
}
```

the calling method code is:

```
private void DocSetExists_Execution(object sender, ConditionalEventArgs e)
{
        DocumentSet docSet = SharepointHelper.GetDocumentSetByPath(workflowProperties.Web, path);
        if (docSet == null)
        {
            e.Result = false;
        }
        else
        {
            e.Result = true;
        }
}
```

I have tried with elevated privlages

```
private void DocSetExists_Execution(object sender, ConditionalEventArgs e)
    {
        SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate
            ()
        {
            DocumentSet docSet = SharepointHelper.GetDocumentSetByPath(workflowProperties.Web, path);
            if (docSet == null)
            {
                e.Result = false;
            }
            else
            {
                e.Result = true;
            }
        });
    }
```

when the workflow calls the xml function it works fine
when it calls the sharepoint function it throws a Sharepoint security exception

my assumption is that it cannot access the dll for documentsets but I would assume sharepoint to have access to such a dll. any ides ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i have solved this issue.

the problem was that the dll was not running under full trust, so you can use any objects other then the SP objects.

if you have deployed your dll to %winroot%\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories{port}\bin

you have to add a elemet to the web config file

i opted to use the gacutil to install it 
Command

```
gacutil /i {path}
```